# Joomla 3 Bootstrap Navbar Mobile Menu botton not responding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, joomla3.0, responsiveness

I have customised my Joomla template by adding Bootstrap trying to a responsive get navbar to work...The problem I have is that the menu button for the responsive navbar isn't responding and shows all the time in desktop above my menu. [image: Screenshot]

```
<?php
/**
* Date         July  31, 2014
* Copyright    Copyright (C) 2014 10templates.com
* License  GPL
*/
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$this->language = $doc->language;
$this->direction = $doc->direction;
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/'.$this->template.'/css/bootstrap.min.css');
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/'.$this->template.'/css/bootstrap.css');

JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');

?>
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1"/>
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/menu.js">"</script> 
<script type="text/css" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/bootstrap-responsive"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!--main container -->
<div class="container-fluid">    
<!--Begin header-->
<div class="header">
<div class="header-inner">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-2" style="none" />
<header class="jumbotron">
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/images/utv_pics/utv_transparent.gif" style="max-width:100%">
<!--Begin Navbar-->
<?php if ($this->countModules('position-1')) : ?>

<div class="nav2">

<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav2">Menu
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>

    <!--a class="brand" href="#"><?php echo $sitename ?></a-->
<div class="collapse nav-collapse" id="#nav2"> 
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="none" />
<!--End navbar-->
<?php endif; ?>
</div></nav></div></header></div></div>

<div class="container-fluid"> 
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="leftCont"></div>

<div id="content" role="main">

<?php if ($this->countModules('position-9')) : ?>
<div class="banners">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-9" style="none" />
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- Begin Content -->
<div class="insider">

  <jdoc:include type="component" />
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-3" style="none" />
</div>
<!-- End Content -->
</div>

<div class="rightCont">
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div></div></div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<footer class="clearfix">
<section>
<?php if ($this->countModules('position-4')) : ?>
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-4" style="xhtml" />
<?php endif; ?>
</section>
<section>
<?php if ($this->countModules('position-5')) : ?>
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-5" style="xhtml" />
  <?php endif; ?>
  </section>
  <section>
  <?php if ($this->countModules('position-6')) : ?>
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-6" style="xhtml" />
  <?php endif; ?>
  </section>
  </footer>
  </div></div>
  <script src="/test/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript">          </script>
 <script src="/test/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">  </script-->
<?php $doc->addScript('templates/'.$this->template.'/js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I noticed that some bootstrap class are missing in Menu area. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

Comment: bootstrap-responsive css file not loading...

Comment: Yes I am seeing that it isn't loading and cannot for the life of me get it to work..I have made changes to the bootstrap class...still same errors.

Comment: I checked from my end it's working good. Could you please remove all overwritten styles. That will help you to fix the Nav problem.
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar

Comment: Thanks Nehemiah is was all those overwritten styles!